# LINQ JOIN and OUTER JOIN - How to turn SQL into LINQ expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I would like to turn the following SQL query into a LINQ expression (using Entity Framework 6.1).  Thus far I have been unable find an acceptable LINQ expression that produces similar results.  Any help turning this simple SQL statement into a LINQ express would be appreciated.

```
SELECT AAG.Id AS GroupId,
   A.Id AS ActivityId,
   A.Title As Title,
   CASE WHEN AA.CompletedOn IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END AS Completed,
   COALESCE(AAG.PointValue, 0) + SUM(COALESCE(AQ.PointValue, 0)) AS PointTotal
FROM ActivityAssignmentGroup AAG
INNER JOIN ActivityAssignment AA ON AA.GroupId = AAG.Id
INNER JOIN Activity A ON AA.ActivityId = A.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ActivityQuestion AQ ON AQ.ActivityId = A.Id
WHERE AAG.AssignedToId = 6
GROUP BY AAG.Id, A.Id, A.Title, CASE WHEN AA.CompletedOn IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END, COALESCE(AAG.PointValue,0)
```

Without the LEFT OUTER JOIN portion, the below LINQ statement is partially complete, but I cannot figure out the appropriate syntax to add the LEFT OUTER JOIN condition:

```
var assignments = await (from g in db.AssignmentGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.AssignedToId == studentTask.Result.PersonId)
                                 join aa in db.ActivityAssignments.AsNoTracking() on g.Id equals aa.GroupId
                                 join a in db.Activities.AsNoTracking() on aa.ActivityId equals a.Id
                                 select new ActivityListViewModel
                                 {
                                     Id = a.Id,
                                     Points = g.PointValue ?? 0,
                                     Title = a.Title,
                                     GroupId = g.Id,
                                     Complete = (aa.CompletedOn != null)
                                 });
```

Edit:

Thanks for the response Bob.  I attempted to use the DefaultIfEmpty and looked at the resultant SQL query generated by the Entity Framework, but it didn't work.  Prior to making this post, this is the LINQ statement I attempted:

```
var assignments = from g in db.AssignmentGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.AssignedToId == studentTask.Result.PersonId)
              join aa in db.ActivityAssignments.AsNoTracking() on g.Id equals aa.GroupId
              join a in db.Activities.AsNoTracking() on aa.ActivityId equals a.Id
              from aq in db.ActivityQuestions.Where(q => q.ActivityId == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
              group aq by new { ActivityId = aq.ActivityId, Title = a.Title, GroupId = g.Id, Points = g.PointValue ?? 0, Completed = (aa.CompletedOn != null) } into s
              select new ActivityListViewModel
              {
                  Id = s.Key.ActivityId,
                  Points = s.Key.Points + s.Sum(y => y.PointValue ?? 0), //g.PointValue ?? 0, 
                  Title = s.Key.Title,
                  GroupId = s.Key.GroupId,
                  Complete = s.Key.Completed
              };
```

Of course, it didn't work either.  The result was items missing the Id (ActivityId).

Comment: So you just need to add the outer join to your linq?  Sounds pretty straight forward to me.  Not sure why the downvotes.

Comment: I'm not sure about the down votes either.  I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't spent a great deal of time trying to figure it out.  Even tried Linqer to no avail.

Comment: I think you should be using `g.Id` instead of `s.Key.ActvityID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop (and thank you Bob Vale)... the query below works:

```
var assignments = from g in db.AssignmentGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.AssignedToId == studentTask.Result.PersonId)
                          join aa in db.ActivityAssignments.AsNoTracking() on g.Id equals aa.GroupId
                          join a in db.Activities.AsNoTracking() on aa.ActivityId equals a.Id
                          from aq in db.ActivityQuestions.Where(q => q.ActivityId == a.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          group aq by new { ActivityId = a.Id, Title = a.Title, GroupId = g.Id, Points = g.PointValue ?? 0, Completed = (aa.CompletedOn != null) } into s
                          select new ActivityListViewModel
                          {
                              Id = s.Key.ActivityId,
                              Points = s.Key.Points + s.Sum(y => y.PointValue ?? 0), //g.PointValue ?? 0, 
                              Title = s.Key.Title,
                              GroupId = s.Key.GroupId,
                              Complete = s.Key.Completed
                          };
```

The issue was the group by condition and using ag.ActivityId when I should have used a.Id.

Answer (score 3):

You need DefaultIfEmpty() to convert a join to left outer join, documentition from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

```
var assignments = await (from g in db.AssignmentGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.AssignedToId == studentTask.Result.PersonId)
                             join aa in db.ActivityAssignments.AsNoTracking() on g.Id equals aa.GroupId
                             join a1 in db.Activities.AsNoTracking() on aa.ActivityId equals a1.Id into a2
                             from a in a2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new ActivityListViewModel
                             {
                                 Id = a == null ? null : a.Id,
                                 Points = g.PointValue ?? 0,
                                 Title = a == null ? null : a.Title,
                                 GroupId = g.Id,
                                 Complete = (aa.CompletedOn != null)
                             });
```

Comment: Bob Vale - thank you for the response.  My original query works, but isn't complete.  I need to add in a join to the ActivityQuestion collection.

What I'm trying to get is a total of points for the activity.  Points can either be applied at the group level or activity level (and potentially both, though practically unlikely).  I added an edit to show the summation of the points per question.

An activity group can have multiple activities.  An activity can (optionally) have multiple questions (0 to 1 or more).  The final result should be a list of activities and the possible points for it.

Comment: @Aggromonster Look at paqogomez comment to your question, you are using the wrong id in your groupby...

Comment: thank you again.  You are a scholar and a gentleman.  Cannot believe I did not spot that earlier.  Looks like I did get the query right, but failed on my join assignment.